# When using React Native + Expo, where is the iOS API accessed?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, react-native, expo

I'm following the Expo tutorial where you build a simple image-sharing application (https://docs.expo.dev/tutorial/image-picker/).

I'm curious where in node_modules is the actual code that accesses the iOS permissions interface.

For example, in app.js I have the following code:

```
let permissionResult = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
```

The requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync method is located in node_modules/expo-image-picker/build/ImagePicker.js where I find:

```
export async function requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync(writeOnly = false) {
    const imagePickerMethod = ExponentImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync;
    return imagePickerMethod(writeOnly);
}
```

Going to node_modules/expo-image-picker/build/ExponentImagePicker.js I find:

```
import { NativeModulesProxy } from 'expo-modules-core';
export default NativeModulesProxy.ExponentImagePicker;
//# sourceMappingURL=ExponentImagePicker.js.map
```

This is where I'm becoming confused, and I'm not sure how to continue tracing through the modules. I see in node_modules/expo-modules-core/ios/interfaces/Permissions there are objective-c files related to iOS permissions - are these being used in this code example? Where in the code are we actually accessing the iOS API? I have a strong feeling that I'm approaching this question from the wrong angle, so please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: What is your intention for accessing native iOS API?
 Do you want to extend Expo image picker functionalities by writing custom native code?

Comment: My main goal right now is to gain a deeper understanding of React Native and Expo since I'm new to mobile development. By looking at how this particular method from expo-image-picker works I was hoping to see "under the hood" of how the code in app.js translates to the native implementation, if that makes any sense.

Comment: In general, Each React native package requires to access OS native module has Javascript functions that are bound to respective native functions for each device platform.

On top of that, Expo has its own abstraction layer as its package runs inside Expo Go without directly native linking. 

You can start with understanding how to develop native modules in general with React Native.

React team provide an introduction  -https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-intro

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to look at the repository https://github.com/expo/expo/search?q=ExponentImagePicker

Try to find the API names you need.